# Returing a list of strings and iterating over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to iterate through a list of strings after making an ajax call to a controller. In this controller, I am returning a list of strings and I want to iterate over this list in jquery and present it to the screen. Here is my code.

This is my controller

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetComments() {
  var cmts = ex.GetComments(psts, psons);
  var lstCmt = ex.GetCommentsList(cments, psons);

  return Json(lstCmt);
}
```

This is my view:

```html
<div>
  <button id="ldBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button>
</div>
<div id="cments">
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ldBtn").on('click', function(evt) {
      $("#cments").empty();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetComments")',
        data: {},
        success: function(lists) {
          //Something needs to be fixed here
          $.each(lists, function(i, name) {
            $('#comments').append('<p>' + name.Value + '</p>');
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I return the list, I am getting a huge string. How do I fix this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: JSON.parse(string) returns a json object

Comment: 1. Change `dataType` to `'json'`. You're telling jQuery to expect HTML, not JSON. 2.If `lstCmt` is a `List<string>` then there will be no properties in the object which JS receives. Just append `name` directly without the `Value` property.

Comment: try to `console.log` lists. What you get?

Comment: Change ` dataType: "html"` to ` dataType: "json"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why not? The response will be something like `['comment1', 'comment2', 'comment']` isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu exactly but the OP is using `name.Value` - there is no `Value` property as `name` is a string, not an object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks a lot. I got it working!! Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan got you..

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues in your JS code. Firstly you're telling jQuery to expect a HTML response in the `dataType` setting. This is why you see the response as a string. This should be changed to `JSON` instead, that way jQuery will deserialise the response for you.

Secondly you're attempting to concatenate a `Value` property on each item in the list, yet they are strings (as you state you're returning a `List<string>` from your action), and will not have that property. You can simply append the `name` itself. Try this:

```
$("#ldBtn").on('click', function(evt) {
  $("#cments").empty();
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetComments")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(comments) {
      $('#cments').append('<p>' + comments.join('</p><p>') + '</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

I assume the `#comments`/`#cments` discrepancy is only due to amending parts of your code when creating the question.

Also note that I simplified the `append()` logic so that it appends all comments in a single call, which should be slightly faster.